# IntelliJ Ultimate GWTP - Platform not loading archetypes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, gxt, gwt2

I need a bit of assistance in creating a GWT project from scratch and importing the project into my IntelliJ Ultimate.
[image]

**More exactly here is what I had tried so far**:

**a)**

- I had installed the GWT-Plarform into my IntelliJ via MarketPlace.

[image]

- And when I had tried to create a project using the plugin, I can't pass this window because of the archetypes that never appear in the "Select Archetype" list. I had waited for 5 minutes and still nothing.

[image]

I was inspired by the You Tube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhguru8i0VI .

**b)** Besides this, I had also tried a second approach by creating a Maven project that uses the archetype described here https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/guides/getting_started/maven/Archetypes.html

And got stocked at the version number. I don't know with what value to fill the version field in the pop-up window. I had tried 1.0.2, 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT and other versions but none of them had worked.

[image]

**c)**
And lastly but not least I had tried the way the official documentation by downloading the GWT SDK and by using the creating the project using the command line. ( e.g webAppCreator -out foo -templates maven,sample,readme com.example.foo.Foo )

After this, I went into this new project (with the terminal) and run the command mvn gwt:compile. And the output was full of errors.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: You can generate a Maven based GWT project here: http://www.mvp4g.org/boot-starter-nalu/BootStarterNalu.html. Just import it into IntelliJ and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this site. I think this is the only way to generate a correct (and fast) GWT project. I haven't found any other sources.

Comment: I am the Author of Nalu (https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu) and this generator should help you to start quite easy with Nalu. (So, you need to remove Nalu, in case you do not want to use it. This should be quite easy). But, as far as I know, there is no other generator, atm.

Comment: You can also generate a project using the dominokit-cli tool by issuing the following command
`dominokit gen app -t ui -n sample -g org.dominokit.samples` the tool can be found and installed from https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-cli